# Rails 4 - why my controller action executes both html and json response, as seen in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 action with **no** `respond_to` block.But in the logs i can see that the action render twice - one for html and other for json.i am wondering whats causing this.Moreover the id attribute is coming as `[object object]` even after sending a simple string - like this- `Parameters: {"id"=>"[object Object]"}` in the server log.

```
    ###my route code

    get 'halls/:id' => 'home#show_by_location', as: :show_by_location

    ####my homecontroller code

    def show_by_location    

    if params[:id] and params[:id].present?

      ##get only halls address as addressable
      @filter_results_found = false
      if params[:capacity].present?
        ####some business logic added
        @result = ##GETTING SOME RESULT HERE
        if @result.size == 0
          flash.now[:notice] = "No details found" 
        end   
      end
      if params[:food_type].present?
         ###some business logic added
         @result = ##GETTING SOME RESULT HERE
        if @result.size == 0
          flash.now[:notice] = "No halls found in #{@show_by_parameter.capitalize} that allow only #{food_type}" 
        end   
      end

      if params[:rating].present?
        @result = ##GETTING SOME RESULT HERE
        flash.now[:notice] = "No details found in #{@show_by_parameter.capitalize} with rating of #{rating} star(s)"  if @halls.size == 0
      end
      if params[:pricing].present?
        @result = ##GETTING SOME RESULT HERE
      end
    end
      if @filter_results_found  === false
        @result = ##GETTING SOME RESULT HERE
      end        
      @result = @result.paginate(:page => params[:page])

  end



    ####development/server log

    Started GET "/halls/Sydney" for 43.242.228.212 at 2017-12-10 07:28:11 +0000
    Cannot render console from 43.242.228.212! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by HomeController#show_by_location as HTML
      Parameters: {"id"=>"Sydney"}

      ########other logs removed.....
      .........
      ...again below is json rendering for same action




    Started GET "/halls/[object%20Object]" for 43.242.228.212 at 2017-12-10 07:28:24 +0000
    Cannot render console from 43.242.228.212! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by HomeController#show_by_location as JSON
      Parameters: {"id"=>"[object Object]"}
```

i don't think this is a good sign and this causes my server to process the same data that i really don't need.

Comment: It may be beneficial if you show your controller action's code

Comment: added the code structure....@MuhammadIbraheem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, i figured out what was the issue.I am posting it so that it might help someone facing similar problem.

**Problem**

I am using [jquery fileupload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) on my forms to upload images and videos on the go.Now this plugin has a ajax(json) call in the script which is required to load existing images/videos on the page.**Hence it always calls ajax if the script is loaded** and i added the js file in the manifest  - application.js.So every request was called + json call from the script.

**Solution**

i have to remove the js file and then include it explicitly in the form page only where is it needed.This also includes adding a new entry in `assets.rb` to load the script individually instead of the asset pipeline.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( video_upload image_upload )
```

and including the js file **only** in the required template -

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2/video_upload", :media => "all" %>
```

Now the issue is resolved and its just one request in the logs too and also the forms are working with fileupload plugin

Hope this helps someone.